# Create new table by merging two existing tables based on matching field

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am attempting to create a new table using columns from two existing tables and it's not behaving the way I expected.

Table A has 91255063 records and table B has 2372294 records. Both tables have a common field named link_id. Link_id is not unique in either table and will not always exist in table B.

The end result I am looking for is a new table with 91255063 records, essentially all of Table A with any additional data from table B for the records with matching link_id's. I had thought outer join would accomplish this as follows:

```
use database1
SELECT a.*
    ,b.[AdditionalData1]
    ,b.[AdditionalData2]
    ,b.[AdditionalData3]       
  into dbo.COMBINEDTABLE
  FROM Table1 a
  left outer join Table2 b
  ON a.LINK_ID = b.LINK_ID
```

This seems to work when looking at the resulting data however my row total for the newly created table COMBINEDTABLE now has 98011015 rows. Am I not using the correct join method here?

Comment: If you are going to down vote a question it's good form to at least explain your reasoning. How can new coders improve their questions if they don't know what's expected of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you have duplicate LINK_IDs on the right, thus for quite a few rows from Table1, there are multiplle rows from Table2. You could try using DISTINCT in your SELECT, or specify that you want only the records with the smallest or highest identifier column value (if you have one).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I did not realize it would add the extra rows from the right when using a left join. I'll try the distinct selection option and hope that does the trick. :)